# AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials on aws console

Tags: amazon-web-services

I was getting the error "AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentails" in aws console when i want to access my VPC console i was not able to do any thing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Okmdx.png)

I checked the roles and permission, as i am a root user so don't know why this error i am getting,

I checked my laptop date and time and found the time is incorrect, so i sync the timezone and after that again i tried and by this method my problme solved.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjz5x.png)

Comment: Glad you figured it out! If you are publishing this to help future readers who might have the same problem, please create your own Answer and put the solution in there rather than putting the solution in the Question. You can also mark your own Answer as the Accepted Answer.